# Alignment of unordered list "symbol"

Tags: css, html-lists

You can check the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/gkJAd/4/

I have an unordered list in where every *li* will have a max-height of 2.25em (I want it to be at most 2 lines). The list-type should show normally, on the outside, aligned on the first line. I tried a few things all with its on issues:

- If I add the hidden, height, etc, codes to the **li** instead of the **a**, the disc disappears;
- If I change the **a** to be `display: block` instead of `display: inline-block`, it shows correctly on Firefox but wrongly everywhere else;
- If I change the **a** to be `display: inline` it puts the disc at the right place, but, since it is not longer a block, the height is ignored. Anyone got an solution?

Sol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is add `vertical-align: top` to your `ul li a` selector code.

Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gkJAd/8/). Working in FF, Chrome, and IE8/9.

Comment: Fantastic, I got so used to vertical-align been nightly useless that I completely forgot about it.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want.

Basically, I floated and then cleared the `li`s.

Then I gave the `ul li a`s a `display:inline-block` and a `height` and made sure to use `vertical-align:top;`

```
ul{
    margin: 5px 10px 5px 20px; 
    background:green; 
    height:250px;
}

ul li{
    list-style-type:disc;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
} 

ul li a{
    background:green; 
    line-height:1.25em; 
    overflow: hidden;
    display:inline-block;
    height:2.25em;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/gkJAd/6/

*Tested and works in Chrome and FF*

Answer (score 0):

I played with this a bit, but it basically comes down to that `overflow: hidden` will hide the list markers as well. Here's what I came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/N3JGg/

Basically used the display type of `list-item`, then instead of declaring the discs on the outside, pulled them into the box with inside so the overflow wouldn't hide them. It doesn't give you the same, nice line that you had before, but you've got the markers displaying now.